# Solution to $\int_B^{\infty } \frac{B^2 \exp \left(-\frac{Z (x+B) (x-B)}{x}\right) \sqrt{x (x+B) (x-B)}}{x^3} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'd like to find solutions to 
$$F_1(B)=\int_B^{\infty } \frac{B^2 \exp \left(-\frac{Z (x+B) (x-B)}{x}\right) \sqrt{x (x+B)
   (x-B)}}{x^3} \, dx$$ and $$F_2(B) = \int_B^{\infty } \frac{B^2 \exp \left(-\frac{Z (x+B) (x-B)}{x}\right) \sqrt{x (x+B)
   (x-B)}}{x^2} \, dx$$

Neither Mathematica nor Rubi are able to solve these (either the definite or indefinite forms).  I have been able to integrate them numerically in Mathematica, but I'd like symbolic solutions.

Let's label the integrands of $F_1(B)$ and $F_2(B)$ as $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, respectively.  $f_1(x)$ is a probability density function, so $1/F_1(B)$ is its normalization constant.  Hence $F_2(B)/F_1(B)=\left\langle x \right\rangle$ (the expectation value of $x$); note that $f_2(x)= x f_1(x)$.

B and Z are real-valued constants greater than zero; x is real-valued and $x\ge B$.

Given this, $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are continuous and real-valued for $x\ge B$, and thus their integrals should exist and also be continuous and real-valued over this range.

Letting $B, Z = 1$, here are plots of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ for $x\ge B$ which, in this case, means $x\ge 1$:

[image: i]

I can provide detailed background on what these represent (physically) and how I derived them, if that is of interest.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  Yes, of course you're correct. I've eliminated it to clean up the question.   Thanks!

Comment: Keeping $Z=z,B=b$ we have:
$$F_2(b)=\sqrt{2b}b^2\int_0^\infty e^{-2zb x}\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=-\frac{\sqrt {2b}b^2 \pi \sqrt \pi}{2}\sqrt {zb}\left(J_{-\frac34}(zb)Y_{-\frac14}(zb)+J_{\frac34}(zb)Y_{\frac14}(zb)\right)$$
See [$J_n(z)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and [$Y_n(z)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

The first one is way more terrible though: $$F_1(b)=\frac{b\sqrt b}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2zb}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{zb}}-2\sqrt 2\int_0^\infty e^{-2zbx}\frac{x\sqrt x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\right)$$

Comment: @Zacky:  It looks like you might have given me enough for a solution!  For $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-2 z b x) x \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \, dx$, Mathematica gives me (too many charaters to fit into this comment):

Comment: $\frac{\pi ^{3/2}}{16 (b z)^{3/2}} \left (-4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2 J_{-\frac{1}{4}}(b z){}^2-4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2 J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z){}^2+4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2 J_{\frac{3}{4}}(b z){}^2+4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2
   J_{\frac{5}{4}}(b z){}^2-\sqrt{2} J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z){}^2-2 b z J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z) J_{\frac{3}{4}}(b z)+2 b z J_{-\frac{3}{4}}(b z) \left(\sqrt{2}
   J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z)+4 b z J_{\frac{3}{4}}(b z)\right)+2 b z J_{-\frac{1}{4}}(b z) \left(4 b z J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z)+Y_{-\frac{3}{4}}(b z)\right) \right)$  I'll just have to check these numerically

Comment: @Zacky I have checked these expressions numerically. Specifically, I calculated several values of ⟨⟩ using these symbolic results, and compared them to those obtained from high-precision numerical integrations in Mathematica (WorkingPrecision = 1000, MaxRecursion = 100). The individual values are, to within the precision of the numerical calculation (1000 significant figures), identical. Mathematica gives the difference, in quadrature, as $<10^{−1001}$. You might want to consider posting these as an answer.  For your convenience, in case you want the Tex code for the result of....

Comment: ....$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-2 z b x) x \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \, dx$, it's \frac{\pi ^{3/2} \left(-4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2 J_{-\frac{1}{4}}(b z){}^2-4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2
   J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z){}^2+4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2 J_{\frac{3}{4}}(b z){}^2+4 \sqrt{2} b^2 z^2
   J_{\frac{5}{4}}(b z){}^2-\sqrt{2} J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z){}^2-2 b z J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z)
   J_{\frac{3}{4}}(b z)+2 b z J_{-\frac{3}{4}}(b z) \left(\sqrt{2} J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b z)+4 b z
   J_{\frac{3}{4}}(b z)\right)+2 b z J_{-\frac{1}{4}}(b z) \left(4 b z J_{\frac{1}{4}}(b
   z)+Y_{-\frac{3}{4}}(b z)\right)\right)}{16 (b z)^{3/2}}

Comment: All I did was to use the substitution $x=bt$ and obtain: $$\small F_2(b)=b^2\sqrt b\int_1^\infty \frac{\exp\left(-zb\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)\sqrt{t-\frac{1}{t}}}{t}dt\overset{t-\frac{1}{t}=y}=b^2\sqrt b\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-zb y}\sqrt y}{\sqrt{4+y^2}}dy\overset{y=2x}=b^2\sqrt{2b}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2zbx}\sqrt x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$
Everything else was spited out by Wolfram so I don't think I'm fit to post an answer here, but I'm glad if it worked out in the end for you.